# Packing cylinders in a sphere: Phase transition?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

Let $S$ be a unit-radius sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
and $c$ a cylinder of length $L$ and radius $\epsilon$.
It appears to me that for $L \in [\sqrt{2},2]$
and small $\epsilon$,
the optimal packing of congruent cylinders $c$ into $S$
bundles them parallel inside a larger cyclinder $\cal{C}$.
The configuration for $L=\sqrt{2}$ is shown below.

---

### [image: CylSph]

Here the three red segments, each of length $\sqrt{2}$,
show that augmenting this arrangement with an additional cylinder
seems impossible.
(The packing shown follows a lattice, but imagine instead
following an optimal packing of disks in a circle.<sup>1</sup>)
For $L < \sqrt{2}$, it appears there is what amounts to a phase
transition, with the optimal packing no longer just a parallel bundle.

Several questions:

> ***Q1***. To be specific, for $L=\sqrt{2}$ and small $\epsilon$,
> is there a different
> packing that fits more cylinders into $S$?
> I haven't proven the claim, partly because of Q2:

> ***Q2***. How can the claim that the bundle configuration is optimal
> be phrased sharply? With $\epsilon > 0$, it seems one can only
> claim a nearly parallel bundle, and letting $\epsilon \to 0$
> seems problematical.

> ***Q3***. Can you point me to other packing phase transitions that
> might shed light on cylinders in a sphere? I suspect
> that, for smaller $L$, there are several other phase transitions.

---

> <sup>1</sup> Graham, Ronald L., Boris D. Lubachevsky, Kari J. Nurmela, and Patric RJ Östergård. "Dense packings of congruent circles in a circle."
> *Discrete Mathematics* 181, no. 1-3 (1998): 139-154.
> [PDF download](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/98_01_circles.pdf)